# Read string representation of 2D array from CSV column into a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a pandas dataframe, for which one of the columns holds 2D numpy arrays corresponding to pixel data from grayscale images. These 2D numpy arrays have the shape `(480, 640)` or `(490, 640)`. The dataframe has other columns containing other information. I then generate a csv file out of it through pandas' `to_csv()` function. Now my issue is: **my 2D numpy arrays all appear as strings in my CSV, so how can I read them back and convert them into 2D numpy arrays again?**

I know there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any that really focuses on 2D numpy arrays. They seem to be mostly about 1D numpy arrays, and the solutions provided don't seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

As requested, I am adding some code below to clarify what my problem is.

```
# Function to switch images to grayscale format
grayscale(img):
  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Iterating through my dataframe (called data), reading all image files, making them grayscale and then adding them to my collection.
grayscale_images = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  img_path = row['Image path']
  cv_image = cv2.imread(img_path)
  gray = grayscale(cv_image)
  grayscale_images.append(gray)

# Make numpy array elements show without truncation
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

# Adding a new column to the dataframe containing each image's numpy array corresponding to pixels
data['Image data'] = grayscale_images
```

So when I'm done doing that and other operations on other columns, I export my dataframe to CSV like this:

```
data.to_csv('new_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

In a different Jupyter notebook, I try to read my CSV file and then extract my image's numpy arrays to feed them to a convolutional neural network as input, as part of supervised training.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import re

data = pd.read_csv('new_dataset.csv')
# data.head() -- It looks fine here

# Config to make numpy arrays display in their entirety without truncation
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

# Checking if I can extract a 2D numpy array for conversion from a cell.
# That's where I notice it's a string, and I'm having trouble turning it back to a 2D numpy array
image_arr = data.iloc[0,0]
```

But, I'm stuck converting back my string-type representation from my CSV file into a 2D numpy array, especially one with the shape `(490, 640)` as it was before I exported the dataframe to CSV.

Comment: What is the reason for storing the dataframe as a CSV file? Will it be read by another program that requires a CSV input? If not, I suggest using pickle.

Comment: @DYZ I will be reading from the CSV (as a dataset) in a TensorFlow model, because I'm creating a convolutional neural network using Keras, to classify the images. Do you still recommend pickle?

Comment: If your CSV file is simply temporary storage, then I recommend using pickle.

Comment: @DYZ Actually I wish to share it with other colleagues as well, and it's not really temporary storage. I guess that's where I'm undecided.

Comment: @IsaacAsante Can you share some examples of all the relevant data, and any related code? How are you planning on reading the CSV?

Comment: @AMC Alright sure. I've just updated my answer to add relevant parts of my code. I hope this can help clarify my issue.

Comment: @IsaacAsante That `.iterrows()` loop should go. Not only is it notoriously slow, I believe you can accomplish the exact same thing using `.apply()` and similar method. How large is your program? I would love to be able to take a look at it in its entirety, as there may be other areas which could be tweaked.

Comment: Also, you didn’t share one of the most important elements, the data!

Comment: `to_csv` writes a `str` representation of the array(s) to the file.  That is not designed for reconstructing the arrays.  You have to contend with lots of `[]` and missing commas.  And with (480, 640) shape arrays I bet there are ellispes, `...`.  In that case, reconstructing the source is hopeless. Values are missing.

Comment: @AMC The images I'm processing in my program exceed 400MB in size. As for the data, it's the CK+ (extended) database for emotion detection... also known as the Cohn-Kanade Extended database. The images and their emotion labels are dispersed in so many folders by default in the database, so I've consolidated them all under one dataset as part of my ETL operations. The dataframe contains everything I need now (the image data as numpy arrays and their corresponding labels), but it's the 2D numpy array conversion to strings that's killing me.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, I've got around the ellipsis issue by adding the line `np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)`, which makes my 2D numpy array show in full, both when I'm exporting and reading back the CSV. I guess you're right that `to_csv()` isn't designed for reading back to 2D numpy arrays. I'm just not sure what other option I have now. It's my first time trying that...

Comment: @IsaacAsante It doesn’t matter if we don’t get the exact data, it just has to be representative. I’m not at my computer right now so I can’t check what the NumPy array string will look like in the CSV.

Comment: In previous SO questions people have loaded `str` arrays.  What they've had to do is take each string, remove the brackets, split on nl, and then on space, and create a list of lists, which can then be turned into an array.  In other words, good old-fashioned string manipulation and parsing.  There aren't any short cuts that I'm aware of.

Comment: You can share your pickle files with your colleagues as well. As long as you do not plan to feed your CSV files into third-part software *that is capable of recognizing numpy arrays as strings*, there is no point in using CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a csv with array strings:

```
In [385]: arr = np.empty(1, object)                                             
In [386]: arr[0]=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                     
In [387]: S = pd.Series(arr,name='x')                                           
In [388]: S                                                                     
Out[388]: 
0    [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
Name: x, dtype: object
In [389]: S.to_csv('series.csv')                                                
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
In [390]: cat series.csv                                                        
0,"[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]"
```

load it:

```
In [391]: df = pd.read_csv('series.csv',header=None)                            
In [392]: df                                                                    
Out[392]: 
   0                                                1
0  0  [[ 0  1  2  3]\n [ 4  5  6  7]\n [ 8  9 10 11]]

In [394]: astr=df[1][0]                                                         
In [395]: astr                                                                  
Out[395]: '[[ 0  1  2  3]\n [ 4  5  6  7]\n [ 8  9 10 11]]'
```

parse the string representation of the array:

```
In [396]: astr.split('\n')                                                      
Out[396]: ['[[ 0  1  2  3]', ' [ 4  5  6  7]', ' [ 8  9 10 11]]']

In [398]: astr.replace('[','').replace(']','').split('\n')                      
Out[398]: [' 0  1  2  3', '  4  5  6  7', '  8  9 10 11']
In [399]: [i.split() for i in _]                                                
Out[399]: [['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9', '10', '11']]
In [400]: np.array(_, int)                                                      
Out[400]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

No guarantee that that's the prettiest cleanest parsing, but it gives an idea of the work you have to do.  I'm reinventing the wheel, but searching for a duplicate was taking too long.

If possible try to avoid saving such a dataframe as csv.  csv format is meant for a clean 2d table, simple consistent columns separated by a delimiter.

And for the most part avoid dataframes/series like this.  A Series can have object dtype.  And each object element can be complex, such as a list, dictionary, or array.  But I don't think `pandas` has special functions to handle those cases.

`numpy` also has object dtypes (as my `arr`), but a list is often just as good, if not better.  Constructing such an array can be tricky.  Math on such an array is hit or miss.  Iteration on an object array is slower than iteration on a list.

===

`re` might work as well.  For example replacing whitespace with comma:

```
In [408]: re.sub('\s+',',',astr)                                                
Out[408]: '[[,0,1,2,3],[,4,5,6,7],[,8,9,10,11]]'
```

Still not quite right.  There are leading commas that will choke `eval`.

Comment: Your detailed answer largely contained the solution for my issue. I just made a few tweaks, but thanks a lot for this! I was able to combine everything in a single function after making changes to the code, and run it on the "Image data" column of my dataframe, using the `apply()` function in Pandas. It's all good now; all image data strings are now converted to 2D numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

data = pd.read_csv('new_dataset.csv')

Method1:  data.values

Method2:  data.to_numpy()

If data.shape is 2D DataFrame, then the above two methods will give your 2D numpy array.
Have a try!

---

Here is a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": [np.random.randn(480, 640), np.random.randn(490, 640)], "B": np.arange(5, 7)})

print(type(df.to_numpy()[0, 0]))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(df.to_numpy()[0, 0].shape)  # (480, 640)

print(type(df.to_numpy()[1, 0]))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(df.to_numpy()[1, 0].shape)  # (490, 640)
```

I'm going to work in a while, you can try it first, and ask again if you have any questions.

Comment: @Isaac Asante,  It happens that I am familiar with the work you are doing，data.values or data.to_numpy() will give what you need.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand how this helps OP.

Comment: He just hopes to convert the DataFrame read from the previously-stored CSV into numpy, which is often done in academic work related to machine learning.

Comment: No, that’s not what he’s trying to do. Have you read the post?

Comment: @AyiF Hmm... thanks, but sorry, that does not solve my issue. I do get numpy arrays returned, but they're arrays of strings, and the shape is wrong. They also contain `\n` characters, and so on.

Comment: @IsaacAsante That’s because this answer has nothing to do with your issue, it won’t solve anything...

Comment: @AMC Yeah, I figured I'd still try to give feedback. Someone else above said I might have to do good old fashioned string manipulation... which I'm hoping not.

Comment: @IsaacAsante Bah, I think you have multiple options here, no need to worry.

Comment: @IsaacAsanteI， It ’s not clear what your specific data looks like. If it is a grayscale image, it should not be a string, but a number from 0 to 255. If it is a string format number, you can try it yourself first, such as removing '\n'.  Go to work in a while, you can continue to leave messages to solve details.

Comment: @AyiF What do you mean by _if it is a string format number, you can try it yourself first, such as removing ‘\n’_? _If it is a grayscale image, it should not be a string, but a number from 0 to 255._ Reread OP’s post again, you’ve misunderstood which part of the data is a string. Also, while 0-255 (AKA 8 bits) is a common format/range for grayscale images it isn’t the only one, so we need to be careful about this kind of assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Add two columns to the `data` dataframe : the grayscale image to converted to bytes using `np.tostring()` and the original shape.

```
grayscale_images = []
grayscale_shapes = []

for index, row in data.iterrows():
  img_path = row['Image path']
  cv_image = cv2.imread(img_path)
  gray = grayscale(cv_image)
  grayscale_images.append(gray.tostring())
  grayscale_shapes.append(gray.shape)
```

Read the CSV, then recover the 2d np array using 'np.fromstring()` and reset the correct shape.

```
  imagedata = np.fromstring(df.loc(...))   # index the image cell
  imagedata.shape = df.loc(...)            # index the corresponding shape
```